# Spring cloud gateway replaces plus sign with space

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I have configured path in spring cloud gateway as follow:

```
        - id: api-challenge
          uri: ${local.api}
          predicates:
            - Path=/v1/api/challenge
          filters:
            - SetPath=/api/challenge
            - SecureHeaders
            - JwtAddGatewayTokenFilter=xxx
```

and when I call directly this gateway with parameter which is ISO time with plus sign:

```
/v1/api/challenge?time=2023-04-07T11:10:06.763+02:00
```

to API I see forwarded time with plus sign replaced with space escaped sign : %20:

```
/api/challenge?time=2023-04-07T11:10:06.763%2002:00
```

Why is it so and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really related to spring cloud gateway.

If you were to create a very simple `@RestController` like this

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @GetMapping("/v1/api/challenge")
    public String hello(@RequestParam String time) {
        return "Challenge time = " + time;
    }
}
```

You would get the following output when called with `/v1/api/challenge?time=2023-04-07T11:10:06.763+02:00`

```
Challenge time = 2023-04-07T11:10:06.763 02:00
```

This is because in URL encoding, a "+" sign is used to represent a space character.

If you want to interpret the value of the request param properly, it will need to be encoded in the URL using `%2B`

That way, `/v1/api/challenge??time=2023-04-07T11:10:06.763%2b02:00` would result in

```
Challenge time = 2023-04-07T11:10:06.763+02:00
```